# MS Access keyword search optimization

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am sure this subject has been touched on a lot, but after hours of googling I'm afraid I can't find the answer I need. All I am really looking for is a direction, a path to follow to learn what I need. I have a MA Access database and I am trying to write a keyword search query, but I want to get a really wide range of results from my query. It's easy enough to say `description LIKE "red"` but I am looking for more powerful searches. Something that would return even parts of the searched words, so if I search "clipboard" I want to find "surfboards" too. What I would really like is to be able to do a keyword search that would return a ton of results but have a way of ranking them based one relevancy to the original search. Any ideas?

Comment: Use wildcards and a lot of code? :)

Comment: Haha thanks. That's where I'm at now and I've been getting decent results for close word matches, but I want to get a lot more results and not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: You could start stripping letters off either side and run with wild cards, each letter removed reduces the match %, similarly, replace central characters with ? wildcard. See also VBA for soundex & Levenshtein : http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Comparing_Words:_Levenshtein_Distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between words. Levenshtein distance measures the difference between two sequences. This would allow you to consider resembling words as well.

The Levenshtein distance ranges from 0 (words are equal) to length of longest word (words are completely different). You might want to transform the Levenshtein value to a more appropriate value.

```
Dim maxlength As Long
Dim similarity As Single

maxlength = Max(word1.Length, word2.Length)
similarity = (maxlength - levenshteinDist) / maxlength
```

This yields values for similarity between 0 (not similar) to 1 (equal).

You can find VBA implementations here:
[Levenshtein Distance in Excel - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243652/880990)
[ms access - Finding similar sounding text in VBA - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607709/880990)

Note: Access does not have a `Max` function. Write your own or code it explicitly.

Comment: That definitely looks like a great place to start! Thanks! I'll have to dive into that a bit and see where I get.

Comment: Levenshtein works great as a ranking system! Thanks a ton! Now I just have to work on getting more results so I have something to rank.